# linear independence in Euclidean space

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose that $\alpha$ be a nonzero vector of Euclidean space $V$.  $\alpha_1,...,\alpha_n\in V$, satisfying 
$$(\alpha_i,\alpha)>0,\: i=1,...,n;\quad (\alpha_i,\alpha_j)\le0,\: i,j=1,...,n, \:i\neq j.$$
Prove that $\alpha_1,...,\alpha_n$ are linearly independent.

Comment: I assume this is a space over $\Bbb R$.  I'd find it easier to think about the problem if we used $v_i$ as the vectors because I usually use Greek letters as scalars.

Comment: What is $(\alpha_i,\alpha)$ referring to, is that a distance?

Comment: @Tom That's the standard notation for the Euclidean, usual, inner (or scalar) product